# Multiple NSStreams inside a NSStream, NSNetService with multiple streams

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstream, nsnetservice

Basically i use NSNetService, which provides you with one i/o stream pair

```
- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didAcceptConnectionWithInputStream:(NSInputStream *)inputStream outputStream:(NSOutputStream *)outputStream
```

I need to use however multiple streams at the same time...

***How to have multiple NSStream working inside an NSStream?*** so i can have multiple streams working with NSNetService

Comment: find any kind of solution? im running into a problem trying to reuse the same variables where my program glitches out.

Comment: nope, if you find any solution, please let me know